# Should Spring Cloud Contract tests actually call an external service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-cloud-contract

I'm having trouble finding out the answer to this..

I'm exposing an endpoint, JSON data is being sent to it.

Inside my service I'm then mapping this to a POJO, serialising to a JSON request, then firing that on to my service via OpenFeign (internal service within company).

Should I be mocking everything in terms of the response?  Or are contract tests meant to test this integration?

Currently I am analysing the actual response from the service I'm calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the producer side, your controller should have all the services mocked. It means that it will not call a database nor another service to get back the response. What you should do is to create a simple controller object and inject fake / mocked services that will return fixed responses. Contract tests are about checking if you can communicate, not about checking if the functionality is working fine.

Comment: correct, that's exactly what i mean. in the base class when you pass the controller to the standalone mode of RestAssured mockmvc, you can create your controller and pass in a service e.g. sth like this `new MyController(new MyService1() { Object doSth() {/ return "return some value instead of going to the database or call another service"; } });`

Comment: I deleted my question because I thought it was stupid!

For anyone reading this I asked - do I create a simple controller in my test package and call that with mocks.

Thanks Marcin

Comment: An issue I'm having is having to declare `@RestController` in my test controller.  This is leading to an ambiguous call from my API, presumably it doesn't know whether to call the real controller or the test one.  Am I missing something here?  Or should I just mock the original controller?

Comment: Or should I create a test endpoint specifically for the contracts?

Comment: You don't have to start the spring context at all. Just create the controller via new. Please check the spring cloud contract samples for now information

Comment: This has worked wonderfully, thank you for your help and pointing me towards the samples.  Spring is.....amazing!